# SQL: Create new database options explanation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

When creating a new database in SQL SERVER, there are many options.

[image]

Can any of you guys please help me in understanding all these options?

Any explanation/links/help well appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  You can't honestly expect people to list the definition of all of these settings for you...

Comment: Yes, I know..that's why I mentioned "Any expl.../LINKS...."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The db creation options and their significance is discribed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190249%28SQL.90%29.aspx). This is for SQL server 2005, a link provides options for 2008 on the same page. Hope that helps.

Comment: Exactly what I needed... BTW what did you searched for to reach that link? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The options are all documented on MSDN.

The [documentation for CREATE DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) may shed some light on the immediate database options.

The [documentation for SET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx) lists all the database-level options that can be set.

Comment: Thanks for the link...I did saw it before posting the question but I'm still not sure if all of the options (shown in the image above) have been explained.. :-(

Comment: They're all in there - mostly in the documentation for SET.  Remember that anything you can do in the management interface, you can do with a Transact-SQL statement.